# I can't play either YouTube or online video in my android app

Tags: android, video, playback

I'm quite novice to android development. 
I tried several methods that have been found by googling and they all just fizzled out.
So, can anyone help me how to clear that problem?
I'll be so grateful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1g_ouW6Tos")));
```

is enough for that operation.

**Edit:**
If you want to add webview use that example;
Add your layout a webview;

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then in your class add this codes;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    detailView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
    detailView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1g_ouW6Tos");
}
private class Client extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
It works good but it's not what i asked for...
It actually opens a video in new browser. But what i want to do is to play that video in my own android app.
Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: You can implement a webview to your layout. Then load this url on that webview. It is a simple solution.

Comment: @user2163787 i added another solution to my answer see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + video_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can also try like this.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185128/what-i-need-to-play-mobile-youtube-videos-in-my-own-webview